# Value after decimal Place not being calculated in Javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal, point

Hello All I am using Javascript to calculate some values of textboxes .The calculations become only for the value before decimal places but when i enter the value after a point then it make no nay effect on result.Here is my JS code and formulas in it

**Update**

```
var pkrusd;
pkrusd = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtpkrusd').value, 10); 
var ratelb;
ratelb = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtRatelb').value, 10);
//Per 10 lb
var pertenlb=roundNumber(((pkrusd*ratelb)/400)*10,2);
parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtpertenlb').value)=addCommas(pertenlb);
//PEr 100 lb
var perhundlb=roundNumber(pertenlb*10,2);
parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtper100lb').value)=addCommas(perhundlb);
```

Comment: After your update your question is no longer clear.

Comment: Sir I Only want to show zero in results for example if make (91.00*100.00)/100 then it should return 91.00 but in current formula it return only 91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of `parseInt`. The `int` in `parseInt` is an abbreviation for "integer" which means "whole number".

Comment: Thanks Brother its working answer will be accepted with in 8 minutes

Comment: Brother is there any way to consider also 0 in calculations results.When there is result like 50 it shows only 5.but i want to show 50 in result

Comment: Totally.  Also, for future reference, if you're parsing an Int to base 10 you don't need to pass the ",10" arg unless you're worried about values that may imply a different conversion (like if you might have a leading "0x" in the string)

Comment: parseFloat( '50' ) //-> returns 50.  Is something else truncating your string?

Comment: Sir Please View My Update i used parsefloat in resultant but this is not returning any thing

Comment: @user1220667: Just a side-note... `parseFloat` takes only **one** parameter. Please read the docs I linked to. The docs are for your benefit.

Comment: Where is docs and also I am passing only one parameter to parseflaot for result